# Deleting previous items in object when iterating over data Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Outside my scope I have:

```
var imageData = {};
```

Then I iterate over my data with jQuery `.each` like such:

```
    $.each(imgData, function(imagesI) {
        imageData = imagesI.QuoteImage;
                    console.log(imagesI);
    })
```

So when I console log `imagesI` I get back so many objects (it's different each time) for example my console log looks like;

```
Object {theImage: "select_q26", Info: "Some info", InfoMeaning: "Info Meaning"}
```

However, whenever I `console.log` my object outside which is `imageData` I only ever get the last object I get from iterating over my data.

Is there anyway to add each object I get back to the variable above without overriding the last one I added?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want imageData = [] and imageData.push(imagesI.QuoteImage)

Comment: Yup. I was going about it the wrong way. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array and push the values to that

```
var imageData = [];

$.each(imgData, function(imagesI) {
    imageData.push( imagesI.QuoteImage );
});
```

Comment: I tried `.push` but pushing to an object instead of an array. Thanks dude! This worked :)